# SQl : Get all rows if date is nul

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a php function in which i am taking 2 parameters ,`start_date` and `end_date`

I also want if both dates are Null then this function should return the all rows

Here is my mysql query

```
select COUNT(*) from demo_meeting where meeting_datetime > "2013-01-01 OR NULL" and  meeting_datetime < "2013-09-10 OR NULL";
```

THis query is working properly if both dates are available if i am using both date as NULL it is returning the Zero rows .

PLease tell me how can i improve this query so that if both date are NUll then it could return the all meetings

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this query is working is working properly? How this `"2013-09-10 OR NULL"` is a valid date value?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal   select COUNT(*) from demo_meeting where meeting_datetime > "2013-01-01 OR NULL" and  meeting_datetime < "2013-09-10 OR NULL";
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       20 |
+----------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`richardo` has given good solution but you can do like this also:

```
select COUNT(*) from demo_meeting
where (meeting_datetime > "2013-01-01" and  meeting_datetime < "2013-09-10") 
      or (meeting_datetime  is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($start_date) &&  empty($end_date)){
     $sql="select COUNT(*) from demo_meeting where meeting_datetime > '$start_date' and  meeting_datetime < '$end_date'";
}else{
     $sql="select COUNT(*) from demo_meeting";
}
```

Comment: `isset` will return true if `$start_date` = `""`.

Comment: might want to use `empty` to be sure

Comment: I can use this with small modification